# How to migrate question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On other SE sites there is option when flag a question for mark it is a candidate for other SE site. There isn't such thing on Freelancing. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome edem!

In order to have a migration path, the question needs a couple things:

1. To be on topic for another site
2. Not a a low quality question for the target site
3. Less than a certain age (I can't remember the exact age right now...)
4. Moderators need to choose up to 5 sites to migrate questions to

I don't believe step 4 has been completed, as no one has brought it up yet. If there is a question that should belong on another site, flag it for Mod Attention, and let us know where you expect it to be. If it passes checks 1-3, then we can migrate it to any SE site. If it fails, we can let you know.

Comment: As a FYI, the limit is 60 days and the 5 sites to choose from (if you're talking about user initiated migrations) can't be set on a beta site like this one